# How to union multiple data source (database and CSV) in Tableau

Tags: union, tableau-api

Does anyone know how to union multiple data sources with same data structure in Tableau?

i would like to union 1 csv/excel and 1 table from mysql.

I have tried the outer join between them but no luck.

Thanks

Comment: Use Blending...

Answer (score 0):

You can use data blending to use multiple data source in a single one.
Link :https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/multiple_connections.html